# Cross-referencing in markup language in Emacs

Tags: emacs, markdown, markup

I am using markdown, restructured text  (markup language) or LaTeX when writing documents. For example, [doconce](https://github.com/hplgit/doconce) can generate LaTeX, HTML, Ipython and other formats.

Although Doconce is very convenient in writing a few pages, it becomes cumbersome writing a few hundred pages. There is no problem writing hundred pages in LaTeX using Emacs/AucTeX/RefTeX ( I can easily cross- reference: Type `C-c (` and this shows an outline of the document with all labels of a certain type [figure, equation]). The same for citations.

I would like to use same features for labels, references, citations. Below is a example of small `doconce` document (or  [more](http://hplgit.github.io/doconce/doc/pub/tutorial/html/tutorial.html) )

```
===== A Section with Sample Text =====
\label{my:first:sec}

Below the section title we have a *label*,which can be used to refer to Section ref{my:first:sec}. 

Equations can be referenced too. 

!bt
\begin{equation} u(t)=e^{-at} label{eq1a}
\end{equation}
!et

References to above equation  such as ref{eq1a}. For more information about the equation, see cite{Miller_200}

===== References =====

    BIBFILE: papers.pub
```

I would like same  RefTeX features in Doconce. When type `C-c (` it should show an outline of the document with all labels in the document or cite from the the `papers.pub` file (Doconce relies on the [Publish](https://bitbucket.org/logg/publish), which is very similar to BibTEX file.)

I think cross referencing missing in other markup languages (markdown, restructured text, asciidoc, etc.), so this question could be expanded to them too.

Comment: Is your question how to do RefTex-like cross-referencing in Doconce?

Comment: Yes but the same principle may be applied to other markup languages. Because the syntax is very  similar.